# Shazam / SoundHound Music Analysis - Recommendation for Reading

Tags: audio, frequency-spectrum, reference-request, music

I need to explore some area around music frequency analysis.
A good example is the way [Shazam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam_(application)) / [SoundHound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundHound) app works (mapping frequency domain, comparing, creating some vector map, handling noises and errors).

I am looking for a while for a ***practical*** book or articles about this. By practical i mean with a simple language/code examples, etc.

No Sigmas, and integrals for infinity that takes you back to university.

It's really hard to find any music/audio analysis practical material.

Comment: I'd start with [Music Information Retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_information_retrieval).

Comment: Um, sorry, to understand spectral analysis, you'll have to do some math. That doesn't have to take you back to the parts of university *you didn't enjoy*, but honestly, you're asking for an introduction to a very mathematical thing, so there's no way around understanding a few of the tools that the people building that thing used. Look at the article Royi linked to – while it doesn't have any formulas itself, you'll notice that …

Comment: … importantly among the tools used are things like *Mel-Frequency Cepstral Coefficients*; you'll have a hard time understanding what these are without slinging a few series around, and maybe feeling reminded of a Fourier Integral once or twice or several times.

Comment: I actually understand the subject but don’t necessarily need math. I built a “Shazam” for simple music toy that recognize a song only with a simple FFT and some vectors algorithms. By math I mean theoretical, I need practical( FFT can look very hard using math while in reality it’s just a for loop and a basic simple concept.) One math professor Eric Weinstein talked exactly about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is called - Music Finger Printing.

Searching for it will yield many results.
I'm attaching few good ones I found:

- [How Does Shazam Work](http://coding-geek.com/how-shazam-works/)?
- [How Does Shazam Work? Music Recognition Algorithms, Fingerprinting and Processing](https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/shazam-it-music-processing-fingerprinting-and-recognition).
- [Creating Your Own Shazam (Identify Songs) with Python Through Audio Fingerprinting](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/973/creating-your-own-shazam-identify-songs-with-python-through-audio-fingerprinting-in-ubuntu-18-04) (The [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRsNZa45prE)).
- [Audio Fingerprinting with Python and Numpy](https://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/).
- [Fingerprint Audio Files & Identify What's Playing](https://github.com/itspoma/audio-fingerprint-identifying-python).
- [Playing with Shazam Fingerprints](https://aubio.org/news/20091111-2339_shazam).

Reading all those won't teach the exact rigorous Math, but it will give you intuition and tools to start with.

Comment: Thanks so much, that’s a really good start!